# mht file while creating crystal report in vs2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have installed vs2010 and crystal report scn long time ago. I am working on a new project and trying to create a report but when i click on crystal report if form mht file, while the same is working fine in previous project. I tried to re-install, re-start many times but still the issue.. any suggestions

Comment: What version of Crystal Reports are you using?

Comment: Vs2010,and scn sap crystal report for it. CR FOR VS 13_04

Comment: When you set the target framework to ".NET Framework 4", is CrystalReportViewer present inside the Toolbox (in Reporting tab)?

Comment: Yes, it is. I can view the reports.

Answer (score 2):

So, since your only problem is the creation of a new report document, try downloading the latest version of Crystal Reports from here http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824 . The mht file is usually shown when you doesn't have the CR package installed on VS 2010. Maybe a newer version will correct the issue.

Comment: Problem presisted even i downloaded. I cleared the history as i found a trick on website and it worked.

Comment: @greatmajestics If you find any solution, please always add this solution as answer, this might help others.